# Arquillian/Shrinkwrap MavenDependencyResolver behind proxy

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I'm using Jenkins to execute a Maven Build which includes an EJB integration test using Arquillian.

The server hosting the Jenkins and running the build is behind a proxy, which shouldn't be a problem because the `settings.xml` contains the valid proxy settings. (On my local system with no proxy it's working just fine.)

Resolving the dependencies by maven (while running `mvn install`) works perfectly fine (started manually from bash or by Jenkins) but if I use the `MavenDependencyResolver` of Arquillian I get an Exception:

**Exception**

```
2011-06-09 06:03:59,391 ERROR my.package.test.util.ArchiveUtil - Could not resolve DBUnit Dependency
org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.ResolutionException: Unable to collect dependeny tree for a resolution
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenBuilderImpl.resolveAsFiles(MavenBuilderImpl.java:320)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenBuilderImpl.resolveAs(MavenBuilderImpl.java:376)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenBuilderImpl.resolveAs(MavenBuilderImpl.java:353)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenBuilderImpl$MavenArtifactBuilderImpl.resolveAs(MavenBuilderImpl.java:450)
    at my.package.test.util.ArchiveUtil.createTestArchive(ArchiveUtil.java:125)
    at my.package.test.util.ArchiveUtil.<clinit>(ArchiveUtil.java:36)
    at my.package.test.util.AbstractTest.createTestArchive(AbstractTest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.invoke(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:162)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.generateDeployment(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:100)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.generate(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:55)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.deployment.DeploymentGenerator.generateDeployment(DeploymentGenerator.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:98)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:126)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:106)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:98)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:126)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.core.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:106)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:170)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:303)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$300(Arquillian.java:45)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:187)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.4.8 ()]
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:251)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:267)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:314)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(MavenRepositorySystem.java:176)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenBuilderImpl.resolveAsFiles(MavenBuilderImpl.java:316)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.4.8
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:275)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:419)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:233)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.dbunit:dbunit:pom:2.4.8 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:499)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:260)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.dbunit:dbunit:pom:2.4.8 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:934)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:925)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:681)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:675)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.get(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:420)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:411)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Error transferring file: Connection timed out
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.resourceExists(LightweightHttpWagon.java:357)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:566)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.resourceExists(LightweightHttpWagon.java:334)
    ... 4 more
```

**Java Source**

```
//...
try {
    ear.addAsLibrary(DependencyResolvers
            .use(MavenDependencyResolver.class)
            .artifact("org.dbunit:dbunit:1.4.8")
            .resolveAs(JavaArchive.class).iterator().next());
} catch (Throwable t) {
    LOGGER.error("Could not resolve DBUnit Dependency", t);
}
//...
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

How can I make sure this java code gets there is a proxy (if the missing proxy is the issue). Do I have to use environment variable or a settings.xml?

Is there an other solution to get this dependency with Shrinkwarp, e.g. as a `jar`? (I guess this would be my preferred solution.)

**Environment Details**

- Server OS: Ubuntu 10.04
- Maven 3.03
- Jenkins 1.413 running on Tomcat 7
- Arquillian 1.0.0.Alpha5

Thank you.
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

proxy support for dependency resolution is not currently supported.

However, you can specify a path to settings.xml, which is used to activate specific repositories mentioned directly or in active (activated profiles).

See for comprehensive example:

https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver/blob/master/impl-maven/src/test/java/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/impl/maven/integration/ProfilesUnitTestCase.java

Basically, to summarize settings.xml magic:

1. By default, `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`
2. Can be overridden by setting a system property `org.apache.maven.user-settings`
   or `org.apache.maven.user-settings`
3. Can use `MavenDependencyResolver.configureFrom(path-to-settings.xml-file)` in your test

Cheers,

Karel

Comment: thank you again! like i mentioned early this day in irc: the `MavenDependencyResolver` tries to get the artifact from the online repository even when it exists in my local repo. that's why i load it with `MavenArtifactResolver` (http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowDoIAddJARFilesToTheTestArchive) even though it might be an outdated solution it simply works...

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem I'm running into as well. I've tried setting the `-Dhttp.proxyHost -Dhttp.proxyPort` on the JVM running the test, but still with no success.  I finally had to resolve the Maven dependency via command line so that it would download to my repository before the test would start working.  It would seem reasonable to assume that the Maven dependency resolver, running with the JVM, would utilize the `HttpConnection` class of the JVM to download the library.  That's not the case, apparently.