# Shrinkwrap resolver plugin behind proxy

Tags: shrinkwrap

I am using the 2.0.0-alpha-1 version of shrinkwrap-resolver-bom in my POM file. When I try to execute Arquillian test cases, it seems Shrinkwrap resolver suffers the presence of company proxy in that the deployment is very, very slow due to long timeout for artifact tranfer operations. I keep getting org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.LogTransferListerer transferFailed.
I found [Arquillian/Shrinkwrap MavenDependencyResolver behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291146/arquillian-shrinkwrap-mavendependencyresolver-behind-proxy/6292726#6292726) explaining what to do with version 1.0.0, I guess, but I don't know what how to handle this with version 2.0.0.
Any suggestions?
Thanks
Massimo

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution:

- add the missing Shrinkwrap dependencies in your pom, so that Maven will download them and install them in your local repository (+ Nexus if you have one)
- remove the previously added dependencies in the pom. Now that the dependencies are in the local repo, shrinkwrap should find them without trying to connect to Maven Central